# Pandas apply function to every second row of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to alter the text on every second row after interpolation the numeric values between rows.

```
    stamp     value
0   00:00:00  2
1   00:00:00  3
2   01:00:00  5
```

trying to apply this change to every second stamp row (ie 30 instead of 00 between colons) - str column

```
    stamp     value
0   00:00:00  2
1   00:30:00  3
2   01:00:00  5
```

function to change string

```
def time_vals(row):
    #run only on odd rows (1/2 hr)
    if int(row.name) % 2 != 0:
        l, m, r = row.split(':')
        return l+":30:"+r
```

I have tried the following:

```
hh_weather['time'] =hh_weather[hh_weather.rows[::2]['time']].apply(time_vals(2))
```

but I get an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows'

and when I try:

```
hh_weather['time'] = hh_weather['time'].apply(time_vals)
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Any ideas?

Comment: expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use `timedelta` instead of `str`

The strength of Pandas lies in vectorised functionality. Here you can use `timedelta` to represent times numerically. If data is as in your example, i.e. seconds are always zero, you can floor by hour and add 30 minutes. Then assign this series conditionally to `df['stamp']`.

```
# convert to timedelta
df['stamp'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['stamp'])

# create series by flooring by hour, then adding 30 minutes
s = df['stamp'].dt.floor('h') + pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)

# assign new series conditional on index
df['stamp'] = np.where(df.index % 2, s, df['stamp'])

print(df)

     stamp  value
0 00:00:00      2
1 00:30:00      3
2 01:00:00      5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#convert string value to timedelta (better to work with time)
df['stamp']=pd.to_timedelta(df['stamp'])

#slicing only odd row's from `stamp` column and adding 30 minutes to all the odd row's
odd_df=pd.to_timedelta(df.loc[1::2,'stamp'])+pd.to_timedelta('30 min')

#updating new series (out_df) with the existing df, based on index.
df['stamp'].update(odd_df)

#print(df)
    stamp   value
0   00:00:00    2
1   00:30:00    3
2   01:00:00    5
```

Comment: `df[1::2]['stamp']` Strongly recommend you never use chained indexing. It's explicitly discouraged in the docs and there are alternatives, e.g. `loc`.

Comment: Could you add some comments on what this does and why it solves the problem?

Comment: Edited the answer, pls check